# Will Repercussion deal damage to a controller beyond a creature's toughness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Repercussion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Repercussion)'s text reads as follows:

> Whenever a creature is dealt damage, Repercussion deals that much damage to that creature's controller.

So: if, for example, a 1/1 creature is dealt 10 damage with Repercussion in play, does its controller take 10 damage or 1?

Comment: It's as you said: The creature was dealt 10 damage, and Repercussion deals that much damage.

Comment: Sure. It just seemed too broken to not be banned/restricted.

Comment: @intuited nah, it's not a particularly strong card. Dealing massive amounts of damage to a creature isn't that much easier than doing the same to a player. Sure, it can make a cool combination with something like Earthquake, but that's a difficult enough interaction to exploit that Repercussion is _nowhere near_ strong enough to be banned or restricted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The controller takes 10 damage. A creature's toughness does not limit the damage it can take. Toughness just indicates how much damage is enough to destroy it.